# remove colon from conference proceedings citation

Tags: bibliographies

I am using latex bibliography package to generate my bibliography, but it appears to be adding a colon after "In" for conference proceedings. Is this correct? and if not is it possible to remove it?

```
\documentclass{template}
\begin{document}

\cite{egelman}


\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{thesis}

\end{document}
```

Example citation....

Egelman S, King J, Miller RC, Ragouzis N, Shehan E.  Security User Studies:  Methodologies and Best Practices.  In:  CHI ’07 Extended Abstracts on Human Factors in Computing Systems;2007. p. 2833–2836.

```
@inproceedings{egelman,
author = {Egelman, Serge and King, Jennifer and Miller, Robert C. and Ragouzis, Nick and Shehan, Erika},
title = {Security User Studies: Methodologies and Best Practices},
year = {2007},
booktitle = {CHI '07 Extended Abstracts on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
pages = {2833–2836},
numpages = {4},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: By “ latex bibliography package”, do you mean the `biblatex` package? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I am using a template and cannot see any reference to which package it is using for the bibliography in the tex file. The only reference to bibliography is the two I have given above. Not sure that helps?

Comment: @TobiBS thanks I have added some more info. I am new to latex so not 100% sure where how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why "In: " shows up in the formatted bibliographic entry is that the `vancouver` bib style expects/requires the `editor` field for entries of type `@inproceedings` to be non-empty. Consider listing "Mary Beth Rosson" (the conference chair) and "David Gilmore" (the program chair) as the editors. While you're at it, do also consider providing `publisher` and `address` fields.

The following screenshot shows the result (highlighting added) of adding the `editor` field to the entry.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{thesis.bib}
@inproceedings{egelman,
  author       = "Egelman, Serge and King, Jennifer and Miller,
                  Robert C. and Ragouzis, Nick and Shehan, Erika",
  title        = "Security User Studies: Methodologies and Best
                  Practices",
  year         = 2007,
  editor       = "Mary Beth Rosson and David Gilmore",
  publisher    = "Association for Computing Machinery",
  address      = "New York, NY",
  booktitle    = "CHI~'07 Extended Abstracts on Human Factors in
                  Computing Systems",
  pages        = "2833--2836",
  numpages     = 4,
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}

\begin{document}
\cite{egelman}
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, so this it is normal for Vancouver to have the colon. When I add an editor in it the colon remains and it says        In: Doe J editor. ChI '07 ......   again I assume this is now correct when using Vancouver. Final question, is there a different type which can be used for conferences which does not include the colon? many thanks